# RxJava: interval operator is not returning infinite sequence

Tags: rx-java2

As per RxJava documentation, interval operator 'create an Observable that emits a sequence of integers spaced by a given time interval'. I written below program, but the subscribe method is not getting called. Am I missed anything here?

```
Observable<Long> observable = Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(Long t) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(t);
    }

});
```

I am using 'io.reactivex.rxjava2' version 2.2.6

Comment: Recommended reading: [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#getting-started).

Comment: This code works just fine for me as it is, unless you wanted something other than printing numbers infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explored, Observable data push is happening in daemon thread, to make my application work, I should hold the main thread for some time, so observable has chance to fire the event. I updated the code like below to make the application run.

```
Observable<Long> observable = Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(Long t) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
        System.out.println(t);
    }

});

Thread.sleep(5000);
```